# Problem with IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'd like to implement the folloing function.

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Read()
{
...
}
```

If i try to complie the project, an compiler error occured.

Type not found.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you're returning `IEnumerable<T>`, but you're not specifying `T`. Your signature should look something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Read<T>()
{
...
}
```

Comment: There are other options, including putting this in a generic class, or defining a specific type, such as IEnumerable<int> Read()...

Answer (score 7):

When you put this:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Read() {...}
```

You're declaring a generic return type (`IEnumerable<T>`), but for this to work, the compiler needs to be able to figure out what "T" means. One of three things has to happen.

1) You can implement this inside of a generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    // T is now the type of MyClass<T>
    private static IEnumerable<T> Read() {...}

}
```

In this case, the return type will be the same as the generic type of the containing class.  This means that you'd call this (since it's static) like:

```
var results = MyClass<int>.Read();
```

2) You can implement this in a generic method.  In this case, you should change the declaration to:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Read<T>() { ... }
```

This lets the compiler know, at method call time, what type of `IEnumerator<T>` will be returned.  You'd call this like:

```
var results = MyClass.Read<int>();
```

3) You can specify a specific type, if the Read() method always returns the same type.  For example, if your method is always reading integers, you could do:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Read() { ... }
```

And then call this as:

```
var results = MyClass.Read();
```

Comment: Good overview of all possible options.

Comment: See, this is why you have 47k and I only have 13k. :)

Comment: Well... you have been around a few months less than me, and here you are with triple the rep... yeah, I guess I can call that an obsession. :)

Answer (score 1):

You either need to do one of four things:

Add to the top of your source file:

```
using System.Collections.Generics;
```

Enclose the method in a generic class:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    private IEnumerable<T> Read() {
        //
    }
}
```

Make the method generic:

```
private IEnumerable<T> Read<T>() {
    //
}
```

Replace `T` with a known type, for example:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Read() {
    //
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Collections;
```

Or possibly

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: You will need a reference for both. Collections defines IEnumerable and Collections.Generic defines IEnumerable<T>

Comment: He could remove the reference to System.Collections.Generic and just use IEnumerable (no generic parameter) to get around the problem.

Comment: Yeah, totally missed that missing <T>.